# weak self be used in DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, memory, memory-leaks, grand-central-dispatch, ownership-semantics

Here is a simple API class as shown below.

```
class API {
    func fetchData(_ callback: @escaping (Data) -> Void) {
        // reqeust to server...
        callback(response)
    }
}
```

When we call `fetchData` in the code below, we use `[weak self]` to prevent retain cycles.
I'm using `DispatchQueueue.main.async` to update the UI in the main thread.
Do I need to have `[weak self]` here too?
Which one is right, `fooA` or `fooB`?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let api = API()
    
    func fooA() {
        api.fetchData { [weak self] data in
            self?.doSomething()
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.updateUI(data)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fooB() {
        api.fetchData { [weak self] data in
            self?.doSomething()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.updateUI(data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Do I need to have [weak self] here too?* - no, you don't.

Comment: Of course `[weak self]` must be in 2 places. Both blocks are independent, and asynchronous. you may get completion of fetchData, schedule execution of updateUI, and before it has time to happen, your view controller is ready to die. So to die peacefully, it needs that second [weak self]

Answer (score 0):

`weak` and `unowned` propagate:

```swift
api.fetchData { [weak self] data in
  // do something with self
  DispatchQueue.main.async { // weak inherited
    // update UI with data
  }
}
```